# GStreamer streaming video to public IP address

Tags: linux, gstreamer

Here is my GStreamer streaming pipe:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! \
    x264enc tune=zerolatency byte-stream=true \
    bitrate=3000 threads=2 ! \
    h264parse config-interval=1 ! \
    rtph264pay ! udpsink host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port=5600
```

and the associated GStreamer receiving pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5600 ! \
    application/x-rtp,\
    encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! \
    rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! \
    autovideosink
```

My problem is when I enter my public IP address instead of xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. I can't receive my video. But when I use my local IP video it is receiving. 
Does anyone knows where is the problem. I'm opening both pipelines on the same PC, maybe this is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should monitor the traffic with a tool like Wireshark.
If on Linux, you can look at the loopback (lo) interface.

Also, there is an `address` property on `udpsrc` you can set:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5600 address=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ! \
    application/x-rtp,\
    encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! \
    rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! \
    autovideosink
```

Comment: i have tried with address property, and now i got this error:

`Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Could not get/set settings from/on resource.
Additional debug info:
gstudpsrc.c(1494): gst_udpsrc_open (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0:
bind failed: Error binding to address: Cannot assign requested address
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...`

Is it possible that GStreamer streams only on local network and that it's not possible to stream over public IP?

Answer (score 0):

I am working with `tcpclientsink` to send and `tcpserversrc` to receive. Turns out in tcpserversrc, I have to use the local IP address, but in tcpclientsink I can use the external IP, and hence send from another computer over the Internet. My receiver is on a Google Compute Engine instance. Dunno if this is specific to that, or holds for gstreamer in general.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would check is router settings. Ensure you properly configure a firewall rule to allow an external source to establish a connection to sink inside the network. By default, most home routers are configured to block outside sources from establishing a connection with anything inside a network. Look into NAT, port forwarding, and DMZ options to expose a particular device inside network to the outside via a port forwarding rule, and ensure firewall rule is relaxed for port 5600 on that device.

Note that opening ports and creating allow rules in your router/firewall can expose you to outside threats. Make sure you know what your doing.